# JDBC MYSQL FK implementation

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to implement FK relation from MySQL into JAVA using JDBC. I have a list of `Garaz` objects and each `Garaz` has a list of `Auto` (cars) objects. I have very mixed data.

My MySQl DB is ok and I try to do it like this:

```
public static ArrayList <Garaz> selectRecords() throws SQLException {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    String selectTableSQL = "SELECT Garaz.G_ID, Garaz.Nazwa, Garaz.Adres, Garaz.LiczbaMiejsc, Garaz.LiczbaPoziomow, " +
        "Garaz.Czynny, Auta.A_Id, Auta.Model, Auta.Kolor, Auta.IloscDrzwi, Auta.Rejestracja\n" +
        "FROM Garaz\n" +
        "LEFT JOIN Auta\n" +
        "ON Garaz.G_Id=Auta.G_Id\n" +
        "ORDER BY Garaz.G_Id; ";

    // ArrayList lista = new ArrayList <Garaz>();

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        System.out.println(selectTableSQL);

        // execute select SQL stetement
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            int g_id = rs.getInt("G_ID");
            String nazwa = rs.getString("NAZWA");
            String adres = rs.getString("ADRES");
            int lmiejsc = rs.getInt("LICZBAMIEJSC");
            int lpoz = rs.getInt("LICZBAPOZIOMOW");
            boolean czynny = rs.getBoolean("CZYNNY");

            ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList <Auto>();

            int a_id = rs.getInt("A_Id");
            String model = rs.getString("Model");
            String kolor = rs.getString("Kolor");
            int ildrzwi = rs.getInt("IloscDrzwi");
            String rejestracja = rs.getString("Rejestracja");

            Auto d = new Auto(a_id, model, kolor, ildrzwi, rejestracja);
            if (a_id !=0){
                lista2.add(d);
            }
            Garaz f = new Garaz(g_id, nazwa, lista2, adres, lmiejsc, lpoz, czynny);
            lista.add(f);

            //System.out.println("nazwa : " + nazwa);
            //System.out.println("adres : " + adres);
            // return lista;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

I don't understand how to read from `ResultSet rs` in the way that: `ArrayList Garaz` contains objects (`Garaz`) and each `Garaz` object contains `ArrayList Auto`. So I have big problem with creating 2 lists (one is part of another) by reading data from `rs` (`ResultSet`). I have all `Garaz` and all `Auto` from DB tables, but the relation is mixed. Like `Garaz1` contains random `Auto` (cars).

How do I create 2 lists (one is part of another) to keep the relation `Auto` is part of `Garaz` based on `G_ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the result, check if you already created the `Garaz` object for the `G_ID` of the row and either use that or create a new one. This can be simplified by sorting on the `G_ID` field and just create a new `Garaz` object when the `G_ID` changes.

As you comment that you don't know how to do this, here is a full example:

```
public List<Garaz> getAllGaraz() throws SQLException {
    List<Garaz> garazList = new ArrayList<Garaz>();
    try (
        Connection con = getDBConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
            "SELECT Garaz.G_ID, /* other garaz columns */ " +
                   "Auta.A_Id /*other auta columns */\n" +
            "FROM Garaz\n" +
            "LEFT JOIN Auta\n" +
            "ON Garaz.G_Id=Auta.G_Id\n" +
            "ORDER BY Garaz.G_Id");
    ) {
        Garaz currentGaraz = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            int garazId = rs.getInt("G_ID");
            // Create Garaz only if it is different
            if (currentGaraz == null || currentGaraz.getId() != garazId) {
                // retrieve other columns
                currentGaraz = new Garaz(g_id /* + other garaz columns */);
                garazList.add(currentGaraz);
            }

            int a_id = rs.getInt("A_Id");
            // replacement of your condition of a_id != 0
            // 0 could be a valid value, check for null instead
            if (!rs.wasNull()) {
                // retrieve other columns
                Auto auta = new Auta(a_id /* + other auta columns */);
                // The list of Auta is part of the garaz
                currentGaraz.addAuta(auta);
            }
        }
        return garazList;
    }
}

public class Garaz {
    private final List<Auta> autaList = new ArrayList<Auta>();
    private final int id;

    public Garaz(int g_id /* + other fields*/) {
        id = g_id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void addAuta(Auta auta) {
        autaList.add(auta);
    }

    public List<Auta> getAutaList() {
        return new ArrayList<Auta>(autaList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. it sounds like a plan :) Thnx for helping me, I'll try it this evning.

Comment: What about some tips about creating ArrayList of Auto objects, this is a part of Garaz object. I know which Auto (car) goes to which Garaz based on G_id in Auta table

Comment: Make that `List` part of the `Garaz` object and simply add the cars you create from the `ResultSet` (or something like that, solution depends on how you want to use the result). I don't want to be rude, but I would say that being able to think of these kinds of solutions is part of the basic problem solving skills you need as a developer.

Comment: I cant make it work :( All I wana do is to rewrite 2 tables into 2 ArrayLists - why it can't be simple ???

Comment: It is simple (or at least: I think it is). I have added an example of how to do this.

Comment: Ok thnx, I'll try it tonight, but question - you add Auta to ArrayList Garaz, but how you check/decide which Auto goes to which Garaz ? You dont use G_id of Auta table in your code.

Comment: @user2982527 No I don't do that, I add the `Auta` to a `Garaz` object. And because of the `JOIN` condition, it is already clear that the `Auta` belongs to that `Garaz`.

Answer (score 1):

your result set will provide one result (aka line) for each Garaz and Auto, since thats what the select statement does. So you can...

either parse the resultset as it is, and manually create each Garaz & Auto record you want, but you will have to deal with the duplicate Garaz data.

OR

You can either use a framework like MyBatis to get the get the objects back, or.

OR

Perform a SELECT statement for the list of Garaz, then perform another SELECT statement to get the list of AUTO's back for each Garaz.

---

```
Sudo code.....  


@Repository
public class StoreDbDAO 
{
    @Autowired  
    public void init(@Qualifier("dataSourceCDB") DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    private static final String GET_USABLE_RECORDS = "SELECT d.ID, d.HARDWARE_ID " +
            " FROM DEVICE d " +
            " LEFT JOIN TABLEB o on o.X_ID = d.X_ID " +
            " WHERE " +
            " d.DEVC_HARDWARE_ID IS NOT NULL " +
            " AND o.CODE = ?  "";


    public List<Map<String, Object>> getStores(String cCode)
    {
        return simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForList(GET_USABLE_RECORDS, code);
    }
}
```

---

@Autowired
StoreDbDAO storeDbDAO;

public void caller() {
    List> stores = storeDbDAO.getStores();

```
List<Stores> storeRecords = new ArrayList[stores.size()];
for (Map<String, Object> store: stores)
{

  final String storeId = (String) store.get("HARDWARE_ID");
  StoreRecord x = new StoreRecord(storeId)
  storeRecords.add(x);


  List<Map<String, Object>> devicesInTheStore = storeDbDAO.getDevicesForStore(storeId);
  // convert these into something useful.
  x.setDevicesInStore(convertToList(devicesInTheStore));
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, so: 1. Could you show me how to create 2 ArrayLists (one is part of another based on G_ID) from this rs (ResaultSet) ? I have BIG problem with this, my data are MIXED

Comment: 2. I want to keep it simple for now, i dont know much about fw 3. I tried but: By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time so it didnt work too

Comment: added a sudo example.